# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex and NSTabView

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nsmutablearray, nstabview

My program is a web browser with MMTabBarView.
Problem with closing the tab closes an invalid element by looking at the log.I have seen that from `NSMutableArray * browserViews;` when call `[browserViews removeObjectAtIndex: index];` in willCloseTabViewItem
This is the code :
.h

```
{
    IBOutlet NSTabView *tabView;
    IBOutlet MMTabBarView *tabBarControl;
    IBOutlet NSSearchField *searchField;
    IBOutlet NSView *mainView;
    NSMutableArray *browserViews;
}
- (MMTabBarView *)tabBarControl;
- (ERBrowser *)addWebView:(NSURL *)url;
- (void)addDefaultTabs;
```

.m

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
        {
            if (self = [super initWithWindow:window])
            {
                browserViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
            return self;
        }

- (void)windowDidLoad{
            [super windowDidLoad];
           for (NSTabViewItem *item in [tabView tabViewItems])
                [tabView removeTabViewItem:item];
            [tabView setAutoresizesSubviews:true];
            [searchField setDelegate:self];
            [tabBarControl setDelegate:self];   
        }

- (ERBrowser *)addWebView:(NSURL *)url{
            for (NSView *view in browserViews)
                [view setHidden:false];
            ERTabModel *tabModel = [[ERTabModel alloc] init];
            NSTabViewItem *tabViewItem = [[NSTabViewItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:tabModel];
            [tabView addTabViewItem:tabViewItem];
            [tabView selectTabViewItem:tabViewItem];
            ERBrowser *browserView = [[ERBrowser alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.frame];
            [browserView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
            [mainView addSubview:browserView];
            [browserViews addObject:browserView];
            [browserView setUIDelegate:self];
            [browserView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
            NSLog(@"%@", browserViews);
            if (url)
                [[browserView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
            return browserView;
        }

- (void)addDefaultTabs {
            [self addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
        }

- (MMTabBarView *)tabBarControl {
            return tabBarControl;
        }

// Method called when webView javascript requests new window with request
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        {
            NSLog(@"createWebViewWithRequest!");
            return [self addWebView:[request URL]];
        }
// MMTabBarVievDelegate
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)aTabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem {
        NSUInteger index = [aTabView indexOfTabViewItem:tabViewItem];
        NSLog(@"didSelectTabViewItem Index %ld", (long)index);

        if ([browserViews count] > index)
        {
            for (NSView *view in browserViews)
                [view setHidden:true];
            ERBrowser *browserView = browserViews[index];
            [browserView setHidden:false];
            NSLog(@"Index change focus tab %ld", (long)index);

            [searchField setStringValue:@""];
            [tabViewItem setLabel:[browserView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]];
        }

    }

- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)aTabView willCloseTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
    {

        NSUInteger index = [aTabView indexOfTabViewItem:[tabView selectedTabViewItem]];
            NSLog(@"willCloseTabViewItem Index %ld", (long)index);
       if ([browserViews count] > index)
       {
            [browserViews removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            NSLog(@"%@" @"%ld", browserViews, (long)index);
       }
    }
```

And log :
The program loads the default Tab google.com:

> 2015-03-26 17:51:57.634 ERClient[89171:26065490] didSelectTabViewItem
>   Index 0
>
> 2015-03-26 17:51:59.030 ERClient[89171:26065490] (ERBrowser:
>   0x600000124060)
>
> 2015-03-26 17:52:02.278 ERClient[89171:26065490] didReceiveTitle!

Gmail open in a new Tab:

> 2015-03-26 17:53:51.994 ERClient[89171:26065490]
>   createWebViewWithRequest!
>
> 2015-03-26 17:53:51.995 ERClient[89171:26065490] didSelectTabViewItem
>   Index 1
>
> 2015-03-26 17:53:52.035 ERClient[89171:26065490] (ERBrowser:
>   0x600000124060, ERBrowser: 0x600000121cc0)
>
> 2015-03-26 17:53:53.987 ERClient[89171:26065490] didReceiveTitle!
>
> 2015-03-26 17:53:56.451 ERClient[89171:26065490] didReceiveTitle!
>
> 2015-03-26 17:53:59.003 ERClient[89171:26065490] didReceiveTitle! -
>   **I do not understand why this happens 3 times instead of 2**

Focus on Tab 2 with index 1, I change the focus to the first Tab index 0, and then return back:

> 2015-03-26 17:57:56.384 ERClient[89171:26065490] didSelectTabViewItem
>   Index 0
>
> 2015-03-26 17:57:56.477 ERClient[89171:26065490] Index change focus
>   tab 0
>
> 2015-03-26 17:57:58.206 ERClient[89171:26065490] didSelectTabViewItem
>   Index 1
>
> 2015-03-26 17:57:58.207 ERClient[89171:26065490] Index change focus
>   tab 1

Now I close Tab 2 with index 1:

> 2015-03-26 17:58:55.691 ERClient[89171:26065490] willCloseTabViewItem
>   Index 1
>
> 2015-03-26 17:58:55.691 ERClient[89171:26065490] (ERBrowser:
>   0x600000124060) 1
>
> 2015-03-26 17:58:55.692 ERClient[89171:26065490] didSelectTabViewItem
>   Index 0
>
> 2015-03-26 17:58:55.693 ERClient[89171:26065490] Index change focus
>   tab 0

It turns out that open Tab 1 with a valid title but the content remained on the Tab 2 :
[image]

And if I open another Tab and there will also be displayed gmail
Tell me how to fix it or where to read why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by itself.
The problem was due to the fact that I have a little experience in programming.
Now I will describe why not work.
When you delete an object from NSMutableArray still remained WebView object with the loaded page. It was necessary to add `[browserView removeFromSuperview];`

The code is as follows:

```
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)aTabView willCloseTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
{
    NSUInteger index = [aTabView indexOfTabViewItem:[tabView selectedTabViewItem]];
   if ([browserViews count] > index)
   {
       ERBrowser *browserView = browserViews[index];
       [browserViews removeObjectAtIndex:index];
       [browserView removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

Maybe someone will be useful in the future to create a Web Browser with Tab Bar

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should call the super method per the docs:

```
/* Implemented methods from NSTabViewDelegate. These require a call to super if overriden by a subclass. */
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView willSelectTabViewItem:(nullable NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView didSelectTabViewItem:(nullable NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
- (BOOL)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView shouldSelectTabViewItem:(nullable NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;
```